# Absolute reference with UDF & filtering data in google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, user-defined-functions, google-sheets-api

Hi I am begineer to scripts, here is the code and [googlesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flbMoOaO2PQ2jYsQq0dL3UBlQWsol7wZpxKO-uUtQn0/edit#gid=0) for reference

What i am getting [image]
what i want to achieve [image]
    `/**
    *@param quest1 Question of the note 
    *@param quest1 Answer of the note
    *@customfunction*/
    function DMNOTE(quest1,ans1,quest2,ans2,quest3,ans3,) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var result = quest1+'-'+ans1+','+quest2+'-'+ans2+','+quest3+'-'+ans3;
    return result;
    }`

I want to achieve absolute reference for "quest" parameter and i want it to loop for rest of the coulmns till column where i enter the function.Also under "Formula Required" column i have put formla for reference thats how i want my UDF to work.

Follwing up i need to filter "Non-solicit agreement" and keep only "No" under it and Copy & Paste all colums highlited in blue to update tab.

```
function toFilter (){
// filter and retain "no" in non-solicit agreement
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn());
var createfilter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues("Yes").build();
ss.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, createfilter);
}
```

Hope i make sense. Any help is appriciated

Comment: The first part of your question is not quite clear. What do you mean by `absolute reference for "quest"` What do you pass to the function as `quest` parameters and what is the desired output?

Comment: Do you mean you need to make the number of parameters to be dynamic so that any number of 'quest' and 'ans' can be given to the formula and then these will be returned as a concatenated string?

Comment: Yo don't need to make parameters dynamic if you don't want to - it is a useful option, not a must. But I do not understand what exactly you want to achieve with your script.

Comment: @ziganotschka Column H to O is Q&A of employees. Row 1 is common question and below rows are answers for each employees and i want it to come as Q&A for each employee so row 1 should be constant for all the answers.

Comment: In your spreadsheet row 1 is already constant. For better udnerstanding, can you provide of screenshot of what your table looks before using the script, and what you want it to look like after you execute the script?

Comment: @ziganotschka i have attached screen shot in question i want questions to be present for all answers but you can see in column D it only works for 2nd row below that cell references change.

Comment: @AneesHameed Yes exactly along with cell reference issue which is been discussed in comments

Comment: You can edit the custom function like this, =DMNOTE(A$1,A2,B$1,B2,C$1,C2), add this to cell E2 and then drag the formulas down.

Comment: @AneesHameed thats silly of me not thinking that....and what about making it work for any number of ` quest ` and ` ans ` in formula also fitering part

Comment: I understand now! But I see that you already got a satisfying solution!

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes and thanks for your responses and also it will be great if my fiter issue is adressed i just need to select whole range filter "non-solicit agreement" and take only data which has "no" paste it in update tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with any number of arguments, you can have a function like below in your script

```
function DMNOTE(...arg){
   let result = ''
   for(let i=0;i<arg.length;i++){
     result += `${arg[i]}-${arg[i+1]},`
     i++;
   }
   return result.substring(0, result.length - 1); 
}
```

And then form your spreadsheet you can call as `=DMNOTE(A$1,A2,B$1,B2,C$1,C2)` or `=DMNOTE(A$1,A2,B$1,B2,C$1,C2,D$1,D2)` The function will process all the arguments being passed and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

### How to `filter "non-solicit agreement" and take only data which has "no"`

The code you provided comes already very close to what you desire, you just need to make the following adjustments:

- `setHiddenValues()` expect an array, no a string, so change `"Yes"` to `["Yes"]`
- `getFilter()` only works to modify a filter that is present in the sheet already, in case there is none, it is better to delete the old filter and create a new one:

```
function toFilter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Worksheet");
  ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn());
  var createfilter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(["Yes"]).build();
  if(ss.getFilter() != null) {
    ss.getFilter().remove();
  }
  ss.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, createfilter);
}
```

### How to `Copy & Paste all columns highlited in blue to update tab`

Build a function that

- calls `toFilter()`
- checks for all rows either they are hidden
- copies the non- hidden rows into an array
- pastes this array to the sheet `Update`

```
function copyIfNotHidden(){
  toFilter();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Worksheet");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Update");
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(sheet1.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)==false){
      array.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```