# googlesheet Copy & Paste filtered data by column name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-api

Hi this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248904/13054972)  works great & I have edited as per my requirement but the problem i have here is i want to copy columns by their header name(Row1) from "Worksheet" and in "Update" sheet instead of copy & pasting whole data.

Here are few column header names: EmployeeID, Email, Date, Employee name, Phone

```
toFilter();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Worksheet");
var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Update");
var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
if(sheet1.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)==false){
  array.push(data[i]);
}
}
sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

Help please !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

//EmployeeID, Email, Date, Employee name, Phone

```
function toFilter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Worksheet");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Update");
  var hA=sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;});
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(!sheet1.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)){
      array.push([data[i][hObj['EmployeeID']],data[i][hObj['Email']],data[i][hObj['Date']]...]);
    }
  }
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

Try it this way if your using an array formula:

```
function toFilter() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Worksheet");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Update");
  var hA=sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  var col='enter column number here'
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){hObj[e]=i;});
  var data = sheet1.getRange(1,1,getColumnHeight(col,sheet1,spreadsheet),sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(!sheet1.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)){
      array.push([data[i][hObj['EmployeeID']],data[i][hObj['Email']],data[i][hObj['Date']]...]);
    }
  }
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var v=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var s=0;
  var h=0;
  v.forEach(function(e,i){if(e==''){s++;}else{s=0;}h++;});
  return (h-s);
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks! but it takes more than 2 minute to execute script when i put array formula in sheet Column A & B `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="","",IF(COUNTIF(E2:2,E2:E)>1,"Yes","No"` but if i put same formula without array `=IF(E2:E="","",IF(COUNTIF(E2:2,E2:E)>1,"Yes","No"`  it executes within 10 seconds why is that? How to ge it execute faster?

Comment: It's probably because the array function messes the lastRow() calculation in getDataRange().  I have a columnHeiight() function that I can use. Can you tell me which column does not contain forrmulas and we can try it and see it that helps.

Comment: Column A & B contains above formula finding duplicates in column E & K respectively and column S contains custom UDF that involves range from K to R. i dont know if this information is required - none of the columns i want to copy has formulas

Comment: Can you share an image of your sheet?

Comment: here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flbMoOaO2PQ2jYsQq0dL3UBlQWsol7wZpxKO-uUtQn0/edit?usp=sharing   columns in yellow formatting contains formula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212153/discussion-between-shiva-and-cooper).